# Android NDK: can't compile my app for armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, android-ndk

:)

I have a big problem with my app, i can't compile it for armeabi-v7a. I have the following Application.mk:

```
# App platform
APP_PLATFORM := android-14

# App abi
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

The compiler runs without any problems, it only gives warning because of --std=c99 flag. While my app now works fine on my HTC One (armeabi), I get the following error from my Samsung Tab3 (armeabi-v7a):

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:761): not a valid ELF executable: /data/app-lib/com.android.main-2/libmylib.so
```

libmylib.so is my own compiled lib.

So what's wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 processor is not ARM.
Samsung used Intel Atom at this specific device which is x86 .

Try [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/ndk-android-application-porting-methodologies) guide for porting .

Comment: It depend on which Galaxy Tab 3 it is.

10.1 - Atom x86;  7 - ARM (Cortex-A9);  8 - ARM (Exynos 4212)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok. Than i had wrong information about the device. But now, i have an other problem. I am using the Un4seen BASS library for my project. My app tells me now (on my Samsung Tab3):

```
dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.android.main-2/libmylib.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libbass.so" needed by "libmylib.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libbass.so" not found.
```

But there is a x86 version of the library, i also have it in my jni folder, and it is even installed to libs by the compiler!?